# What are all the ways to add an object to the local scope in Python?

Tags: python

```
my_var = 3
assert('my_var' in locals())

import a_module
assert('a_module' in locals())

from sys import *
assert('stdin' in locals())
```

I also think you can inject with calls to `locals()` and `globals()`?

Anyway, I love python because it's so explicit with imports. If a name is used, you can usually trace back to exactly where that name was defined. But, I've recently been running into modules wherein I want to find where the name `qux` is defined. The module itself contains no `from something import *`, no `locals` or `globals`, but when I CTRL+F for that name I find it only on the RHS of expressions, nowhere defined!

So my question is this: what are all the mechanisms by which a name can enter the local namespace? Can normal imports inject into my local namespace?

Comment: You can't add things dynamically to the *local* namespace, only to the *global* namespace.  In the example you linked, `iac` will be a global name in the module, and it is indeed undefined.

Comment: Is the name really `qux`? Or is it a module from the Python standard library?

Comment: @Cuadue: Are you sure the code you linked to will run.  It looks likc "iac" is undefined, though it could be injected into the module by other code (which I don't see in that project).

Comment: @NedBatchelder I think you're right, that's a bad example. Maybe I'm imagining it, but I swear I've seen functional code with the same mysterious behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other module may inject the name in this module:

```
#x.py
import y
y.lol = 1
y.func()
```

And this module does not define it:

```
#y.py
def func():
    print(lol)
```

Another crazy way someone may inject code in another module would be:

```
#a.py
import sys
sys._getframe(1).f_globals['lol'] = 1
```

So, `a.py` will inject the name `lol` in whoever import it

```
#b.py
import a
print(lol)
```

Comment: Yes, but that requires that y.py contains `from x import *` doesn't it?

Comment: @Cuadue No. But as Ned Batchelder commented, I also don't see the other modules doing it

Comment: @Cuadue: once imported, a module is an object that can be modified like any other.  So x can import y and then assign new attributes on it, which create new global names in the module.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I'm starting to think the code from the link doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things are basically just fancy assignment statements:

```
# mod1.py
a = 1
import b
from mymodule import c
def d(): pass
class e(object): pass

# mod2.py
import mod1
mod1.f = 17
```

Here we define the names a, b, c, d, e, f in mod1 in six different ways.

Answer (score 0):

In your concrete example, `iac` is mostly likely a global variable exported/injected by one of the following libraries/modules:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import threading
from OSC import ThreadingOSCServer, OSCMessage
import socket
from AddMIDIForwardWindow import AddMIDIForwardWindow
```

My guess is it would be related to the OSC software/hardware (the OSC import).  It appears ISC is the driver for your MIDI hardware and `iac` is the object referrence the library creates to allow you to interface with the ISC driver.

To answer your questions then, things enter the local namespace by being defined in the same block if they are variables/objects.  You may also have something in your "local" namespace if you subclass another class.  So the ways variables can enter into the namespace which you can use are:

1. They are defined locally.
2. They are members of your superclass.
3. They are imported from a module explicitly.
4. They are injected into a module you imported by another module -- such as one imported by one of the modules you explicitely imported.

Comment: `iac` is not defined by any of those imports.  You can see which names are defined: QtGui, QtCode, etree, threading, ThreadingOSCServer, OSCMessage, socket, and AddMIDIForwardWindow.  No other names are defined.

Comment: But it could do this as shown in one of the other answeres:
   `#a.py 
    import sys 
    sys._getframe(1).f_globals['lol'] = 1`